# Finding question marks in cell string

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, excel-2010, match

I would like to find out if a string within a cell in Excel 2010 *contains* any of the following, and then return a '1'.

- `?dementia`
- `? dementia`
- `dementia?`
- `dementia ?`

I've tried some formulas but they don't seem able to get past the use of the wildcard and the string when combined.

Would anyone have any pointers or advice?

[Here is a combination of the suggested answers, and my own work around:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bgJ8.jpg)

Comment: What if you have the string `word?word`?  Do you want to return 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula you need:

`=IF(IFERROR(FIND(A2,$C$3),0)>0,1,0)`

where A2 is the string that you are trying to check.

Comment: Probably the best one yet I can use, many thanks. I have to adjust it to look up two 'dementia' values as the requestor says ?dementia and dementia? are most likely out of the others (its clinical terminology / description). I'll try and post an image to show it working....

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `FIND` function ([Documentation](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-find-function)).

Make sure your search term in in quotation marks.

If you are still having trouble with wildcards, you can try the `CHAR` function ([Documentation](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-char-function)). It will return the character as a string. In your case, to get a ?, you would use `CHAR(63)`. I use [this chart](https://tools.oratory.com/altcodes.html) to keep track of `CHAR` codes (just use the number and ignore the "Alt")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you *don't* want to include `word ? word` and return `1`, you can use something like this:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1,1)="?",RIGHT(A1,1)="?"),1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Useful formula, but I do need to find the wording 'dementia' within a string, which could be at the start middle or end of a cell string.

Answer (score 0):

**REVISED:**

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to search long string in a short string list.

[image]

The formula you can use is:

```
=ISTEXT(LOOKUP(99^99,SEARCH(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$5,"?","|"),SUBSTITUTE(C2,"?","|")),$A$2:$A$5))*1
```

The problem with my prior formula is due to that `?` mark because it is being treated as a wild card.  Here I have replace it with `|` (you can change this to a character that you will never use but avoid `?` and `*`).  This should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks for the formula, it does appear to look up any cell which matches 'dementia' and return a 1. It doesn't matter where the question mark is or how many spaces are before or after it. i.e. 'dementia  ?' will return a 1 as well. Specifically, I need to find those 4 options in the list in A2:A5 in your example.

Comment: @Phil, I have revised my answer to take care of that `?` mark issue.  Take another look.