# EXCEL: Find and Replace, Change Entire Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to :

1. Search if cell contains a certain text (like "orange" in "orange crush")
2. If return true, change entire cell value to "orange"

Up until now, I can search for the cell, and change the specific text to something I want, but not the entire cell (like "orange" to "blue" and have it be "blue crush", which isn't what I want to do. I want it just to be "blue"). I've been doing this with the "find & replace" function.

I've also used the function

```
=if(isnumber(search("orange",B2)), substitute(B2, B2, "orange"), B2)
```

which works!, but prints in the new column I wrote the code, and doesn't replace the value in B2 where it's referencing.

Possibly done in VBA?

What I have:

```
Oranges
Orange slices
Orange
Orange pulp
```

What I want:

```
Orange
Orange
Orange
Orange
```

Comment: Looks very similar to a question that I just answered (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608972/4388883).  Just need to add an `IF` function for your task.

Comment: so if B2 contains "ORANGE" you want the value in B2 to be "ORANGE"

Comment: In Excel, (using strictly formulas anyway), a cell cannot be both an input and an output. If you want to restrict the values allowed in an input cell, then why not just force the user to choose from a drop-down list? This seems like a better solution than letting the user enter anything they want, and then manually changing it to a desired format.

Comment: @ian0411, that is a very good function. Unfortunately like ImaginaryHuman072889 pointed out, I want the input cell changed, and not have the output in an adjacent column. The Find and Replace won't replace the entire cell. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @User91504 If it contains "Orange" anywhere in the cell. There are some cells with more words like "Orange crush". If it is contained anywhere in the cell, I want the entire cell changed to Orange.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 that would be great! Unfortunately I am analyzing data given to me by a company that doesn't have that implemented yet.

Comment: So doesn't work for you???  Maybe show some sample data so we can reproduce the result you want.

Comment: @ian0411 Okay I'll produce a simple example now

Comment: @AndrewWolfe It may be possible to do this with VBA, in which case I suggest modifying your question to add the "vba" tag. But using strictly formulas, it is not possible for a cell to be both an input and an output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do with a formula is:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Orange", A1)), "Orange", A1)
```

If you wanted a case-insensitive search, then use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LOWER("Orange"), LOWER(A1))), "Orange", A1)
```

Then, if you wanted to overwrite the original column, make sure you paste the values over the original column:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @GrantMiller. This works perfectly. Just takes some common sense sometimes, eh?

Answer (score 7):

It is much easier to achieve that:

**Excel -> Open Find and Replace**

**Find what:** `*orange*`

*(`*`-is wildcard for ignore everything before and after "orange". Finds and marks whole cell. Example: Finds cell "small orange shake")*

**Replace with:** `orange`

[image]

Comment: Easy way around

Comment: Best answer! Thank you! I didn't realize I could use wildcards